# Confused about the specs of the project

Tags: matlab, gaussian

Im confused about what the project is saying. It says the following:
[image]

I did the `#1` but in `#2` where do I have to plug `Aij = cos(...)` in inside the code?
I have the code but have no clue where I should plug the given entry `Aij` in. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**`Code`**

```
 n=8;
    for i=1:n
      for j=1:n
        a(i,j)=1/(i+j-1);
      end
    end
    c=ones(n,1);
    b=a*c;
    aorig=a;borig=b;
    %Elimination
    for i=1:n-1
      for j=i+1:n
        m=a(j,i)/a(i,i);
        for k=i:n
          a(j,k)=a(j,k)-m*a(i,k);
        end
        b(j)=b(j)-m*b(i);
      end
    end
    %Back substitution
    for i=n:-1:1
      for j=i+1:n
        b(i)=b(i)-a(i,j)*x(j);
      end
      x(i)=b(i)/a(i,i);
    end
    x'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your Hilbert matrix definition `a(i,j)=1/(i+j-1)` with the cosine expression from #2.